# CVE-2021-4034 vulnerability report from Landscape

Tags: 20.04, security, debian, landscape, canonical

I have a question regarding this CVE. Why this vulnerability is not listed in Landscape when exporting report by CVE ?
https://github.com/mebeim/CVE-2021-4034
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTAcg.png)

Comment: Hello. This is an Ubuntu OS support forum manned by volunteers. So there is no way anyone here can answer your question.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS has been patched for that CVE - https://ubuntu.com/security/cve-2021-4034